# Can automatic failover occur to a DR node on a different data center if synchronous commit is enabled and other conditions are right

Tags: sql-server, windows

Can automatic failover occur to a DR node on a different data center if synchronous commit is enabled and other conditions are right. I'm asking because we had a two node scenario where a primary node was quarantined because of a network issue on the primary site and the AG went into resolving state causing a bit of a lengthy outage. The question is if we had set up the AG to have have automatic failover would it have failed over to the DR on the secondary site i.e not on the same data center?

Comment: I would push back and ask why, specifically, your AG went into the resolving state? Because if it was a simple loss of quorum because the two nodes in the AG are the only voting members, simply adding another voter (whether that be a non-SQL node, file share witness, or shared disk witness) might be a cheaper alternative.

Answer (score 2):

> Can automatic failover occur to a DR node on a different data center if synchronous commit is enabled and other conditions are right.

> The question is if we had set up the AG to have have automatic failover would it have failed over to the DR on the secondary site i.e not on the same data center?

Yes, the AG has no idea what a DR site is, so if it's set to do automatic failover (which requires synchronous commit and be up to date), then it will assuming the cluster survives (that partition has quorum) and no other issues occur (such as hitting the maximum number of failures).

Comment: Note, that configuring the cluster so the DR side can have quorum has the downside that if your primary datacenter becomes partitioned, it will lose quorum, which you may not want.

Comment: Thanks @Sean Gallardy